# how to bind fancybox content form another div content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use Fancybox v2.1.5-0 and try to bind content form another div.

The content image already in another div in HTML page.

Here my HTML Code:

```
Bootstrap 3 carousel
---------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="hotelsd-img">
 <div id="photoCarousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="http:\\www.confirmedrooms.com\hotelbooking\images\hotelimages\1110\031742.jpg" alt="Hotel Name">
      </div>
      <div class="item active">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="http:\\www.confirmedrooms.com\hotelbooking\images\hotelimages\1110\031742.jpg" alt="Hotel Name">
      </div>
      <div class="item active">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="http:\\www.confirmedrooms.com\hotelbooking\images\hotelimages\1110\031742.jpg" alt="Hotel Name">
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

Photo Count
--------------------------------------------------------
<div id="hotelGallery-1" class="photoCount">
    <a href="#" class="openGallery">View all 15 Photos</a>
</div>
```

Now, I want to open Fancybox Gallery on **openGallery** click event.

I have include Fancybox file at head:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
<script src="js/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

JS Code as I try like :

```
$('.openGallery').on('click',function(){
     $.fancybox({

       // Possible code here

     });
  });
```

So, How copy content from **item** div and push into fancybox content and open. Help me to build this.

Answer (score 0):

With `click event` you can achieve it like this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.openGallery').click(function () {
        $.fancybox.open($('.galleryimages').get(), {
             arrows: true,
             padding: 0,
             //Additional Options
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<div id="hotelGallery-1" class="photoCount"> <a href="#" class="openGallery">View all 15 Photos</a></div>
<div class="hotelsd-img">
    <div id="photoCarousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active galleryimages">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/images/1.png" alt="Hotel Name">
            </div>
            <div class="item active galleryimages">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/images/2.png" alt="Hotel Name">
            </div>
            <div class="item active galleryimages">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/images/3.png" alt="Hotel Name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note:

1. You may need `afterClose: function ()`

   ```
   afterClose: function () {
       $('.galleryimages').css('display', 'block')
   }
   ```

   To make sure that images stay visible on page when close fancybox popup (check fiddle).
2. Added `class="galleryimages"` to each image div, It will be better to have custom class to load images as gallery in fancy box instead targeting the default Bootstrap classes `item active`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1m5tth0g/6/)

Comment: I think you didn't get the question, the OP wants a Fancybox gallery, not the whole images in a single fancybox

Comment: @JFK, i missed this line actually `Now, I want to open Fancybox Gallery on openGallery click event.` thanks for pointing out

Comment: @JFK by the way, you always shoot first and ask question later :P